# Regex ".*?" giving same output as ".*"

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

This the file I am using:

```
Shane is a little to play ball
small
silly
```

When I use

```
egrep 's.*l' new
```

I am getting the output as

```
Shane is a little to play ball
small
silly
```

When I use

```
egrep 's.*?l' new
```

I am getting the same output as above, but it should be different.

Comment: If you expect `?` to be a non-greedy modifier (rather than a simple quantifier), that's only supported in *PCRE mode* e.g. `grep -P 's.*?l'`

Comment: so its totally use less in Ubuntu system?

Comment: It's nothing to do with Ubuntu - in grep extended regular expressions (`egrep` or `grep -E`), `.*?` means "zero or more characters, zero or one times"

Comment: any other substitution, i tried using egrep -P but getting the same result!

Comment: user@mario:~$ egrep -P 's.*?l' 1
grep: conflicting matchers specified

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the expected output.

Comment: @ManinderMhn `egrep` is synonymous with `grep -E` - you need to pick **one** regex flavor (basic `grep`, `egrep`/`grep -E` **or** `grep -P`)

Comment: @ManinderMhn BTW `egrep` is deprecated. You should use `grep -E` instead.

Comment: @steeldriver you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Although you say *"it should be different"* you neglect to say what output you expect. As far as I know, the possible interpretations of `?` in a regular expression are:

- In a *basic regular expression (BRE)*, `?` is a literal question mark; since your input contains no such characters, the output of `grep 's.*?l' new` will be empty.
- In an *extended regular expression (ERE)*, `?` is a **quantifier** meaning zero or one of the previous regex atom. In that case, `.*?` means "zero or more single characters (`.*`), repeated zero or one time (`?`)" - this is equivalent to `.*`, and hence `egrep 's.*?l'` and `egrep 's.*l'` will produce identical output.
- In a *perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)*, `?` is a greediness modifier, such that `.*?` in `s.*?l` matches the *shortest* sequence of characters between `s` and `l` whereas the greedy `s.*l` matches the *longest* such sequence. Hence

  ```
  $ grep -P 's.*?l' new
  Shane is a little to play ball
         ^^^^^
  ```

  while

  ```
  $ grep -E 's.*?l' new
  Shane is a little to play ball
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

For simple cases, you can achieve "laziness" without the PCRE `?` modifier by using a negated character set i.e.

```
grep 's[^l]*l' new
```

will match `s` followed by *any characters except* `l`, followed by `l`.

---

ASIDE: `egrep` is technically deprecated - you should get in the habit of using use plain `grep` for BRE, `grep -E` for ERE, and `grep -P` for PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms there's POSIX regular expressions and then there are various extensions, such as Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE), which are implemented in many languages (not just Perl).  The non-greedy modifier *? is a PCRE-specific extension.  In POSIX regular expressions it won't have any special meaning and it'll just regard the ? as redundant.

In grep you can easily switch to PCRE mode with the `-P` command line modifier.